Updating main table to replace 'Email' field with ID of the email located in another 'Email Addresses' Table
I have two tables,
The main table is a list of customers and their contact information.
What I am trying to do is to separate the 'Email' field into a separate table so that I can relate the two because some customers use the same email address.
I have created another table called 'Email Addresses' containing only unique emails and I want to now update the main table with the ID's of the emails from the 'Email Addresses' table but am having trouble with the SQL query.
I have researched and found a solution but it has not worked for me. It comes up with a 'Missing Operator' error.
UPDATE [Main Table]
SET [Main Table].Email = [Email Addresses].ID
FROM [Main Table]
INNER JOIN [Email Addresses] ON [Main Table].Email = [Email Addresses].Email;

What makes more sense is this though I know it will not work:
UPDATE [Main Table]
SET [Main Table].Email = [Email Addresses].ID
WHERE [Main Table].Email = [Email Addresses].Email;

Only new to SQL and still fumbling around in MS Access

Add a number field to Main Table and UPDATE that field with Email Addresses ID. Then when all works, delete Email field from Main Table. Use JOIN clause and place it before the SET clause. Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Does this answer your question? SQL Updating from an inner join

Try these steps:

Change field [Email Addresses].[Id] to an AutoNumber (numeric or
GUID)
Add the field [Main Table].[EmailId] of data type numeric or
GUID matching the Id above
Run this query:

UPDATE 
    [Main Table] 
INNER JOIN 
    [Email Addresses] 
    ON [Main Table].Email = [Email Addresses].Email 
SET 
    [Main Table].EmailId = [Email Addresses].Id;


Remove field [Main Table].Email


That worked!! I couldn't change the 'Main table email ID' to an autonumber because i already had 1 in the table but just changed it to a number type and this worked.

You can try the following SQL
UPDATE [Main Table]
 SET [Main Table].Email = (
      SELECT [Email Addresses].ID 
      FROM [Email Addresses]
      WHERE [Main Table].Email = [Email Addresses].Email
     );

(make sure  [Main Table].Email and [Email Addresses].ID  have a same type)

This comes with an error that says "Operation must use an updateable query"...
